# Raspberry pi camera feedback question (using Yolov8 for instance segmentation)

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I need some help for a project I'm doing. My project is to have my raspberry pi camera detect objects using Ultralytics Yolov8 for instance segmentation. I'm using Thonny for the python code and everything works very well. My python code looks like this:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model=YOLO('best.pt')
model.predict(source=0,show=True)
```

My camera can successfully detect objects on a live camera. I can see frames are getting printed on the bottom of the code saying `0: 480x640 1 Bottle, 2330.8ms`

My question is how can I take the data meaning (0: 480x640 1 Bottle, 2330.8ms) and apply it to send an output signal from my raspberry pi.

Another question would be, where is (0: 480x640 1 Bottle, 2330.8ms) coming from? I don't think it's data coming from a folder I have.

I need the information on each frame to send signals but I don't know where to look. If you know anything or know someone that can help me please let me know. Also, if you have any questions for me please let me know too. Thank you so much!

Comment: this is a question and answer site ... write a clear question and someone will try to answer it ... requests like `If you know anything or know someone that can help me please let me know.` belong at a chat forum, not at this site

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/engine/results/#ultralytics.engine.results.Results. Something like

```
print(results[0].boxes.cls)
```

will print out a tensor of detected classes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133024)